# Expectiminimax in Dice game

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, dice, minimax

I have implemented expectiminimax algorithm for dice game, but it is surely not working properly, could You verify if I implemented it right?

As for now I could as well run random dice choose and 'intelligence' of my AI would be similar, but I don't know what could possibly be wrong with my algorithm.

Flow of the game is like follows (for those of you that don't know dice game):

1. players throw dice
2. players choose dice which they want to throw again
3. players throw dice

My algorithm is as follows, I divided it into 4 parts

```
maxDice = [x,x,x,x,x]
minDice = [x,x,x,x,x]

Max:
for combination in each possible combination of maxDice that max can throw again (including none):
 max = max(MaxChance(combination),max)

MaxChance(combination):
expected = 0
for actualCombination in each possible result of max dice throw:
 maxHand = maxDice - combination + actualCombination //these are set operations of course
 expected += ProbablityOfThrowing(actualCombination)*Min(maxHand)
return expected

Min(maxHand):
for combination in each possible combination of minDice that min can throw again (including none):
 min = min(MinChance(combination,maxHand),min)
return min

MinChance(minCombination,maxHand):
expected = 0
for actualCombination in each possible result of min dice throw:
 minHand = minDice-minCombination+actualCombination
 expected += ProbablityOfThrowing(actualCombination)*Evaluate(maxHand,minHand)
return expected

//for example
Evaluate(maxHand,minHand):
return ValueOfDiceHand(maxHand)-ValueOfDiceHand(minHand)
```

Comment: What makes you think it's not working correctly? Have you tried running tests and seeing if you get the output you'd expect?

Comment: I mean, It is working somewhat,I had small bug, and now I can see that the moves are quite reasonable, but they are not so good as to beat human, this algorithm is behaving too carefully and preservatively.I think that I will have to use reinforcement learning for it.

Comment: That seems like a good idea - reinforcement learning often works well on situations like this. I assume you've already tried just increasing the distance into the future that your algorithm is looking?

Comment: No, i did not, because this part of game has only two steps, i'll try RL and see what wil come out of it, thanks anyway.